# Corresponding English saying for a Spanish one about misfortunes and circumstances?

Tags: idioms, proverbs

There is a saying in Spanish that doesn't translate very well into English:

> Cuando las barbas de tu vecino veas pelar, pon las tuyas a remojar.
>
> **When you see your neighbour's beard plucking[?], get yours to soak.**

I've found a translation [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/cuando-las-barbas-de-tu-vecino-veas-pelar-pon-las-tuyas-a-remojar) that is wrong<sup>1</sup>.

The meaning of the Spanish saying is explained [here](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Ficha.aspx?Par=58407&Lng=0) (in Spanish). In English, it could be translated as:

> If a misfortune strikes someone under circumstances similar to ours, then we should prepare ourselves for the same misfortune.

An equivalent saying in English is also proposed on the same [page](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Ficha.aspx?Par=58407&Lng=9):

> **When thy neighbour's house is on fire, beware of thine own.**
> When the neighbour's house is on fire, beware of your own. (Mieder1992 p. 427)
> When thy neighbour's house doth burn, then look to your own. (Apperson p. 407)
> Look to thyself when the neighbour's house is on fire. (Fergusson n. 153.16 p. 236)
> When the neighbour's house declines, beware the possibilities of your own. (Mieder1992 p. 427)

I find the above saying a bit too formal and I was wondering whether there is a *more modern* and *not so formal* way to express the equivalent meaning.

---

<sup>1</sup> The reason why I consider [this translation](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/cuando-las-barbas-de-tu-vecino-veas-pelar-pon-las-tuyas-a-remojar) wrong is because *"a mistake"* is something we do ourselves; *"a misfortune"* is due to something out of our control.

Comment: Roosevelt said [if your neighbour's house is on fire you lend him your hose and you don't ask for money - what you want is your hose back when the fire has been put out.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HpPvAAAAMAAJ&q=%22if+your+neighbour%27s+house+is+on+fire%22&dq=%22if+your+neighbour%27s+house+is+on+fire%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AhTlU-y4Aa7G7AaxvICYBg&redir_esc=y) But neither that nor OP's examples are exactly "known sayings", so I don't see much point in rewriting anything in "modern English".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think they know the sayings aren't well-known in English, so they want to find the usual (modern, not-so-formal) way of expressing the same meaning ("If a misfortune strikes someone under similar circumstances to ours, then we should prepare ourselves for the same misfortune").

Comment: @snailplane: I suspected as much. Offhand, I can't think of a "saying" with that general sense, but obviously that doesn't mean there *isn't* one. Having said that, I haven't voted on this question yet, but I must admit I'm far from convinced it's even On Topic.

Comment: An alternative translation of the original Spanish: _When you see your neighbor's beard peeling, soak yours._

Comment: The translation that is incorrect actually matches what you're looking for. *Learn from other's mistakes/misfortunes*.

Comment: @SamuelLijin the reason why I chose *"scalping"* instead of *"peeling"* is that I felt using *peeling* would miss the connotation that this is something it gets done to us. This is the same reason why I used the word *"misfortune"* instead of *"mistake"*.

Comment: @Nico, are you saying that the original idiom explicitly says there is some person/agent _causing_ the peeling? I read it as simply observing that peeling is _happening_, but as logic tells us, there must be some reason _for_ peeling to happen. (I chose "peel" instead of "scalp" because "scalp" quite literally means to cut someone's scalp right off their head, which doesn't exactly seem to fit here.)

Comment: @SamuelLijin If we were talking about chicken and feathers I would use "plucking". What word would you use in the case of a man and his beard?

Comment: @SamuelLijin It's hard to explain why the original Spanish saying implies an external action. I think Spanish would use a reflexive verb "pelarse", if we wanted to clarify that a man shaves himself.

Comment: @Nico, I think we're on the same page here - that "pelar" logically, cannot happen without _someone_ "pelar"-ing, and therefore there must be such a someone (or something). I elected to translate into the passive, however, as said agent is not specified.

Comment: pelar also means to shave: http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/pelar which of course makes sense with a beard. 

*Cuando las barbas de tu vecino veas pelar, pon las tuyas a remojar* means *When the beard of your neighbor you see shaving, put yours to soak*. Beards being important. But you're not going to shave a dry beard. There's a significant reason your neighbor shaved/is shaving his beard. Better think about doing it, too.

Comment: @SrJoven I don't see the logic in that interpretation of the Spanish saying. If my neighbour is shaving, why would I want to shave next?

Comment: Idioms don't have to make sense in contemporary times, but please look at the forum post sited in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Now there's a **wake-up call**.

http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/wake-up+call.html

*A wake-up call is a warning of a threat or a challenge, especially when it means that people will have to change their behaviour to meet it.*

Comment: This might be applicable in situations described in the question, but it definitely has a much broader meaning than what's been requested. The wake up call need not be an instance of the event happening to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

> *I've found a translation [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/cuando-las-barbas-de-tu-vecino-veas-pelar-pon-las-tuyas-a-remojar) that is wrong*

What does it say?

> you should learn from other people's mistakes
>
> *is a more modern and not so formal way to express the equivalent meaning.*

Why does this match?

*changed in light of `pelar` also meaning "to shave"*
The verb usage really depends on intent. Your neighbor has shaved his beard, and you should too (soak it, because you're not going to want to shave a dry beard).

In Spanish, this is [addressed in a forum](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/Spanish/idioms_maxims_sayings/769515-cuando_las_barbas_de_tu_vecino_veas_pelar.html) which Google translates as:

> When you see your neighbor's beard peel, put yours to soak it alludes to a saying that we should learn from the problems of others to be on guard and take measures to prevent those same evils can happen to us and so suffer the same fate

The link in the forum points to a [defunct geocities website, referenced here via archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20080316130153/http://www.geocities.com/athens/delphi/3925/dichos/barbas.htm). It in turn references the [Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española](http://fondosdigitales.us.es/fondos/libros/765/1204/tesoro-de-la-lengua-castellana-o-espanola/). `barba` is on [pdf page 279](http://fondosdigitales.us.es/fondos/libros/765/279/tesoro-de-la-lengua-castellana-o-espanola/leer/)/book page 120. It is a long read, in Spanish, which may make more sense to a native speaker than to me. The actual quote is almost midway on [pdf page 280](http://fondosdigitales.us.es/fondos/libros/765/280/tesoro-de-la-lengua-castellana-o-espanola/leer/)/book page 121, on the right hand side.

If the OP has a translation to English of the concept (even in historical terms) from this, it might be helpful to assist.

Comment: The reason why I consider that translation wrong is because *"a mistake"* is something we bring onto us; *"a misfortune"* is due to something out of our control.

Comment: I find this translation inappropriate because of the shift in temporal perspective; this is more akin to hindsight, whereas the original idiom is a warning of sorts.

Comment: so, learn from others misfortunes, but that still fits as more modern. @SamuelLijin, hindsight? I don't follow. If someone is actively making a mistake/encountering a misfortune, it's probably a good time to take action.

Comment: "learn" - to me, at least - implies that the mistakes have not only transpired, but that the repercussions thereof have also transpired, and thus that you know how to avoid both said mistakes and the repercussions thereof. The idiom at hand, however, is more of a cautionary warning - if you see a sign of danger, don't ignore it and get ready ASAP.